# Class 'App\Newuser' not found in Laravel 7.27.0 while trying to implement models in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to use the model method of laravel to insert data into a database, but I got the error message. Even after carefully going through the documentation, I am unable to find any error of my own.
Here is the Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Newuser;

class NewUserRegnController extends Controller
{
       public function submitNewRegn(Request $request){
     
    $first_name         =   $request->first_name;
    $last_name          =   $request->last_name;
    $email              =   $request->email;
    $password           =   Hash::make($request->password, [
                                     'memory' => '1024',
                                     'time' =>  '2',
                                     'threar' =>  '2',
                                    ]);
    // $confirm_password    =   $request->confirm_password;
    $mobno              =   $request->mobno;
    $dob                =   $request->dob;
    $gender             =   $request->gender;
    $address            =   $request->address;
    $country            =   $request->country;
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
    $time               =   date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ");

      $user = new Newuser;

      $user->first_name = $first_name; 
      $user->last_name = $last_name; 
      $user->email = $email; 
      $user->password = $password; 
      $user->mobno = $mobno; 
      $user->dob = $dob; 
      $user->gender = $gender; 
      $user->address = $address; 
      $user->country = $country; 
      $user->time = $time; 

      $user->save();
```

And the Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Newuser extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $keyType = 'bigint';
}
```

Also, how do I make use of prepared statements?
I am a Laravel Beginner, so please explain in easier words

Comment: $user = new Newuser; change As  $user = new Newuser(); and semicolon after $time               =   date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ")

Comment: @chathun `new Newuser` and `new Newuser()` are the same exact thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I had to delete the model, recreate the same one again using `php artisan make:model <modelname>`.

Comment: what did you name the file previously? the name of the file has to match the classname (with same case)

Answer (score 2):

You miss semicolon in this line

```
 $time = date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ")
```

and also replace

```
$user = new Newuser;
```

to

```
$user = new Newuser();
```

Comment: Class 'App\Newuser' not found   This is the new error message

Comment: $user = new Newuser();

Comment: @Asish  use IDE like phpstorm or VS code it will show the syntax errors easily.

Comment: `new Newuser` and `new Newuser()` are the same exact thing

Answer (score 1):

You have created a Newuser object and assigned it to the `$user` variable, and later you try to use `$users` variable (plural). Replace all `$users` with `$user`.

Comment: I figured that out, and already changed them. I also edited the question

Comment: Ok I can see that you modified your code when I was writing my post. Did it help?

Comment: Nope. I still get the same error. That is why I edited my question

Comment: Maybe something's wrong with your autoload file. Try to execute `composer dump-autoload`. It is going to regenerate your autoload file.

Answer (score 0):

This two lines in your model are probably causing the problem:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $keyType = 'bigint';
```